# Python Dataframe setting values for a column based on groups maximum value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following dataframe

```
   id   Area Country
0  11  34.45  Norway
1  12  30.25      UK
2  13  16.70    Iran
3  11  35.45  Sweden
4  13  20.22    Iraq
5  15  35.12     USA

dfObj['BigCountry'] = ''
dfObj['SmallCountry'] = ''
```

Based on the area I want to classify the country either big or small. I was trying to groupby id and then based on max(area) within the group I want to set small/big country

The output should be

```
   id  BigCountry  SmallCountry   
0  11  Sweden         Norway
1  12  UK             UK           
2  13  Iraq           Iran
5  15  USA            USA
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `set_index` then `groupby` and `agg` with `idxmax` and `idxmin`:

```
df.set_index('Country').groupby('id')['Area'].agg(['idxmax','idxmin'])\
  .rename(columns = {'idxmax':'BigCountry', 'idxmin':'SmallCountry'})
```

Output:

```
   BigCountry SmallCountry
id                        
11     Sweden       Norway
12         UK           UK
13       Iraq         Iran
15        USA          USA
```

Comment: Thanks. idxmax and idxmin was completely out of my mind.

Comment: @Inba Would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) this answer.

Comment: What is happening with id column? When I print this it shows only two columns. Is that mean ID column became index?

Comment: I want to have all three columns retained Id, BigCountry and SmallCountry

Comment: Add `.reset_index()` at the end to get the 'id' column from the index.